# Scrapyd S3 feed export "Connection Reset by Peer"

Tags: amazon-s3, scrapy, boto, scrapyd

I'm running Scrapyd with a FEED_URI set to export to S3, but I received the following error at the very end of my scrape. Note that it successfully uploaded a few hundred kb of data to the bucket as the scrape began, then threw this error at the end:

`2014-11-24 10:11:23+0000 [word] ERROR: Error storing csv feed (2285242 items) in: s3://kitchen.bucket/FoodItem.csv
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 783, in __bootstrap
        self.__bootstrap_inner()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 191, in _worker
        result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/feedexport.py", line 101, in _store_in_thread
        key.set_contents_from_file(file)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1291, in set_contents_from_file
        chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 748, in send_file
        chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 949, in _send_file_internal
        query_args=query_args
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 664, in make_request
        retry_handler=retry_handler
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1068, in make_request
        retry_handler=retry_handler)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 939, in _mexe
        request.body, request.headers)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 842, in sender
        http_conn.send(chunk)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 805, in send
        self.sock.sendall(data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 329, in sendall
        v = self.send(data[count:])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 298, in send
        v = self._sslobj.write(data)
    socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

Looks similar to [boto issue 2207](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2207). I'm using gbirke's [MultiFeedExporter](https://github.com/gbirke/scrapy-multifeedexporter), and received a similar error on both of my items.

Comment: I was evaluating duplicity on s3 when I encountered a similar backtrace

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/960